# hangman replacing characters logic

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

```
import random
import sys
words=["tumble","sigh","correction","scramble","building","couple","ton"]
computer=random.choice(words)
attm=7
chosen_word=len(computer)*"*"

print(chosen_word)
while attm>0:
    print(computer)
    print(chosen_word)
    player_guess=str(input("guess: "))
    if len(player_guess)>1:
        player_guess=str(input("enter one character only: "))
    if player_guess in computer:
        print("you're right")
        attm==attm
        for i in chosen_word:    
            player_guess=chosen_word.replace(chosen_word,player_guess)
            print(chosen_word)
    else:
        print("wrong!")
        attm-=1
        
    print("attempts= ",attm)
       
    
        
         
if attm==0:
    print("you lost")
    sys.exit
```

i want whenever the player guesses it gets replaced in chosen_word, the right character replaces the star
if the word is "ton" it'll be displayed like this *** if the player guesse's is (t) the chosen word becomes (t**) and so on
simple syntax is preferable because i'm new in python

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @ForceBru sorry it's confusing but i tried my best to describe the problem, how do i replace stars with characters each time the guess is correct

Comment: That part of the problem naturally belongs in its own function -- one that takes the chosen word and the guessed letters as input and returns the string that you want to display as output. Write, test, and debug that function -- then use it. Trying to do a hangman game without using any functions leads to unreadable code. As far as how to do it -- just build up the string while iterating over the chosen word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change strings in python, they are immutable. Work with lists instead.

Change the `chosen_word` to a `list`, with `list(string)` and replace/change them at the corresponding index. To print, simply use `"".join(list)` to create a new string to print it nicely.

Also, you had an error, where you compared to the chosen wors, which is all `*` instead of the actual letters, so you would never find a match unless you enter `*`.

Here the full example:

```
import random
import sys
words = ["tumble","sigh","correction","scramble","building","couple","ton"]
computer = random.choice(words)
attm = 7
chosen_word = ["*" for i in range(len(computer))]

while "*" in chosen_word and attm > 0:    
    print(computer)
    print("".join(chosen_word))
    player_guess = str(input("guess: "))[0] # take only the first character
    if player_guess in computer:
        print("you're right")
        for idx, ch in enumerate(computer):
            if player_guess == ch:
                chosen_word[idx] = ch
        print("".join(chosen_word))
    else:
        print("wrong!")
        attm -= 1
        
    print("attempts: ",attm)
       
    
        
if attm > 0:
    print("You won!")      
else:
    print("You lost")
sys.exit
```

Comment: `chosen_list = ["*" for _ in computer]` or `chosen_list = ["*" for _ in range(len(computer))]` would be more straightforward ways of creating the list without first creating a word that is created by joining a list of asteriscs.

Also, `attm==attm` is by definition true but is not used for anything, I would also suggest the OP to remove it.

Comment: You also want to change `while attm>0:` to `while "*" in chosen_word and attm > 0:`.  Otherwise, the while loop continues even after the user guesses the correct word.

Comment: I don't understand which variables to use for the condition of winning, two variables must be equal which is computer and an another variable,the for loop you added contains a lot of new syntax that's why i'm confused

Comment: I didn't add change a lot in your code, I just showed you how to properly replace the asterisks in your word. I tried to incorporate some of the suggestions from previous comments as well but I focused on the question you had, which is *how to replace asterisks*.

Comment: @FirasChebil the winning condition is at the bottom (I added it). If the while loop exits, you and you have attempts left, you won. If it exits because you have no more attempts, you lost.

Comment: @FirasChebil I copy pasted my code and it worked without error, both to winning and losing. If you have an error, please post it, your comment isn't at all helpful. thanks.